# Taking of the last word in the line with strtok

Tags: c, strtok

Given a file with the following line:

> word1 word2 word3 word4

I tried to write the following code:

```
FILE* f = fopen("my_file.txt", "r");
char line[MAX_BUFFER + 1];
if (fgets(line, MAX_LENGTH_LINE, f) == NULL) {
    return NULL;
}
char* word = strtok(line, " ");
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    printf("%s ", word);
    word = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
```

For prints the "words".

It's working. But, I don't understand something.

How it's acheive the last word `word4`? (I don't understand it because that after "word4" not exists a space)..

Comment: Aside: the input is from `fgets`, which retains any final newline, so the delimiter string in `strtok(line, " ");` would be better as `strtok(line, " \n");` which will remove the newline.

Comment: Probably `MAX_LENGTH_LINE` is too small. Use `fgets(line, MAX_BUFFER, f)` where `MAX_BUFFER` is at least 500.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani What? You read my question? Everything is ok in my code , but, I ask about what that happens with `strtok`

Comment: I guess you mean *"There is no space printed after word4"* The last token is read as `"word4\n"`, so the space appears after the next line. Do what Weather Vane suggested, to remove '\n'.

Comment: @Software_t the space delimiter given to `strtok` is not *required*. It is a filter. Please read the `strtok` man page.

Comment: `strtok()` scans strings; it stops when it reaches the null that marks the end of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking.  Are you asking how the program was able to correctly read `word4` from the file even though it wasn't followed by a space?  Or are you asking why, when the program printed `word4` back out, it didn't seem to print a space after it?

The answer to the first question is that `strtok` is designed to give you tokens *separated by* delimiters, not *terminated by* delimiters.  There is no requirement that the last token be followed by a delimiter.

To see the answer to the second question, it may be more clear if we adjust the program and its printout slightly:

```
char* word = strtok(line, " ");
for (int i = 0; word != NULL; i++) {
    printf("%d: \"%s\"\n", i, word);
    word = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
```

I have made two changes here:

1. The loop runs until `word` is NULL, that is, as long as `strtok` finds another word on the line.  (This is to make sure we see *all* the words, and to make sure we're not trying to treat the fourth word specially in any way.  If you *were* trying to treat the fourth word specially in some way, please say so.)
2. The words are printed back out surrounded by quotes, so that we can see exactly what they contain.

When I run the modified program, I see:

```
0: "word1"
1: "word2"
2: "word3"
3: "word4
"
```

That last line looks very strange at first, but the explanation is straightforward.  You originally read the line using `fgets`, which does copy the terminating `\n` character into the `line` buffer.  So it ends up staying tacked onto `word4`; that is, the fourth "word" is `"word4\n"`.

For this reason, it's often a good idea to include `\n` in the set of whitespace delimiter characters you hand to `strtok` -- that is, you can call `strtok(line, " \n")` instead.  If I do that (in both of the `strtok` calls), the output changes to

```
0: "word1"
1: "word2"
2: "word3"
3: "word4"
```

which may be closer to what you expected.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't check the return value of `strtok()`, it may be unsafe in some cases.

```
/*  Split string
    @content origin string content
    @delim   delimiter for splitting
    @psize   pointer pointing at the variable to store token size
    @return  tokens after splitting
 */
const char **split(char *content, const char *delim, int *psize)
{
    char *token;
    const char **tokens;
    int capacity;
    int size = 0;

    token = strtok(content, delim);
    if (!token)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    // Initialize tokens
    tokens = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 64);
    if (!tokens)
    {
        exit(-1);
    }
    capacity = 64;

    tokens[size++] = token;

    while ((token = strtok(NULL, delim)))
    {
        if (size >= capacity)
        {
            tokens = realloc(tokens, sizeof(char *) * capacity * 2);
            if (!tokens)
            {
                exit(-1);
            }
            capacity *= 2;
        }
        tokens[size++] = token;
    }

    // if (size < capacity)
    // {
    //  tokens = realloc(tokens, sizeof(char *) * size);
    //  if (!tokens)
    //  {
    //      exit(-1);
    //  }
    // }
    *psize = size;

    return tokens;
}
```